# Deploying custom model on Azure ML Studio

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

In Azure ML Studio, we have the option of choosing a number of inbuilt ML models like Classification, Regression, etc. , which we can drag and drop to our workflow.

My question is, can I upload a custom ML model that I have built locally on my system in Python, and add it to the workflow?

Comment: Did any of the answer solve your issue? Please mark the correct answer as solved or leave a comment if you are still facing some issues thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Take the model.pkl file, zip it, and upload it into Azure Machine Learning Studio. Click the “New” icon in the bottom left:
   [image]
2. In the pane that comes up, click on dataset, and then “From Local File”:
   [image]
3. Select the zip file where you stored your serialized model and click the tick. You expirement should look like this:
   [image]
4. Put the following code to run your classification experiment:

```py
import pandas as pd
import sys
import pickle

def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):
    sys.path.insert(0,".\Script Bundle")
    model = pickle.load(open(".\Script Bundle\model.pkl", 'rb'))
    pred = model.predict(dataframe1)
    return pd.DataFrame([pred[0]])
```

**Update** 
If you want to declare this experiment as an API you need to add web input and output to the Python script module.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have a question, once I've uploaded this pickle file and even if I'm able to access it through code as you demonstrated in section 4, how do I expose it as an API?

Comment: You add a web input and output to the execute Python script module. I will update my answer to let you see

Comment: Thanks a lot! So what I return from the Python script goes back as output to the API with help of the Web service output module right?

Comment: Also, How do I define the signature of the API I'm using? If I want 2 parameters as input from the user, how do I access that form of input from the API in the Python script? Like in Flask we usually access input from the API with a  input = request.args.get('parameter1, default = "", type = str), how do I access API inputs here?

Comment: Actually your parameters are set while you run your prediction experiment. For instance, if you have 12 features in your dataframe (that are actually sent to your Python module), then 12 parameters will be defined as input to your API. After publishing your experiment, Azure will suggest sample Python code for your client application

Comment: So why don't you approve the answer?

Comment: Approved. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to achieve this using the "Execute Python Code" module. See here for documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/execute-python-script

There you can upload contents in a zip bundle file. If you include your trained model there, you might be good to go.

[image]